# Is there a way to get a calendar-popover to the top stack position of my form?

Tags: html, css, angular

I'm currently struggling to fix a form style.
The form contains among other things 2 date elements, where a calendar opens after clicking into it.
The form itself exists at the moment in an old style, where everything is working fine.

[old search form](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Jousc.jpg)

The style needs now to be changed to accordion view, to look like this:

[new search form](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5TbL9.jpg)

As you can see it causes problems by providing a complete visible calendar, because it's not popping over the accordion it belongs to.

I tried already working with the z-index so far, but nothing seems to work.
*Note: z-index was already set to 9999999, before I started playing around.*

I expect the calendar to popover the accordion and not getting cut by the content of the accordion.
(If there are more elements underneath the date-elements, it would look fine, but thats not the case and can't be expected from the form.)

Any idea how to fix it?

**edit of providing css code:**

```
.wc-date-popover{
    font-size: 14px;
    box-shadow: 0 16px 24px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.14), 0 6px 30px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.12), 0 8px 10px -5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
    margin: 0px auto;
    perspective: 1000px;
    float: left;
    background: #fff;
    background: $secondary-color;
    position: fixed;
    width: 90%;
    top: 5%;
    left: 50%;
    z-index: 9999999;
    overflow: hidden;
    height: 90%;
    max-width: 320px;
    transition: all .5s linear;
    transform: translateX(-50%);
}

@media (min-width: 768px) {
    .wc-date-popover{
        width: 250px;
        position: absolute;
        top: 31px;
        height: auto;
        left: 0;
        transform: translateX(0);
    }
```

**edit of providing part of html code**

```
<div class="row {{viewobject['css']}}" id="{{viewobject[g.PROPS.title]}}">
  <div class="col">
    <div class="group">
      <div [formGroup]="form">
        <div formGroupName="{{viewobject[g.PROPS.title]}}">
          <ng-container *ngIf="viewobject !== undefined && form !== undefined">
            <ng-container [ngSwitch]="viewobject[g.PROPS.nodeType]">
              <ng-container *ngSwitchCase="'accordion'">
                <hac-accordion>
                  <hac-accordion-group [heading]="viewobject[g.PROPS.label] ? viewobject[g.PROPS.label] : viewobject[g.PROPS.title] | hasLang" [blnExpand]="true">
                    <ng-container *ngTemplateOutlet="content"></ng-container>
                  </hac-accordion-group>
                </hac-accordion>
              </ng-container>
            </ng-container>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Maybe the accordeon has a `overflow:hidden`, overwrite this style with `overflow:visible`

Comment: The overflow:hidden property will not work correctly as the accordian usually needs this property. One possible way will be to calculate the target height/width and place the calendar it as a fixed element. If you are using any plugin for the calendar then you should have the option to place the calendar according to body. If you can make a plunkr then we can help you in a better way.

Comment: @Roy accordion itself has no overflow property

Comment: @Aslam The date-popover is already in the body of the expanded card.

Comment: Complete the question with HTML code please.

Comment: @Roy any idea so far?